# How to use python to load the website which needs a POST

Tags: python, python-requests

I used the Python requests to log in a website which needs username and password. I succeed to print the website. But how can I open website which has been logged in my browser. I tried to do the work like this, but it doesn't work:

```
signin_req = session.post(signin_url,data=logininfo,headers=headers)
webbrowser.open(signin_req.url)
```

I need you help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you can log in with python, the fact that you logged is not visible to the browser and `webbrowser.open` does not provide a way for you to do that. You would need some way of telling your browser what cookies to use and there is [no way to transfer that to the browser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) as you can see in the documentation.

If you want a way of automatically logging into a website to use in the browser, your efforts might be better spent looking at how to make a JavaScript bookmarklet.